# Spaceship Operator on NaN

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, nan, c++20, spaceship-operator

How does C++ treat floating-point NaN when doing space-ship comparison operations? We know that the usual compares always return false, so how does this change with NaN?

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() <=> std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a wrapper for floating point numbers in C++20 that would enable me to default the spaceship operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445206/is-there-a-wrapper-for-floating-point-numbers-in-c20-that-would-enable-me-to-d)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison), in the case of floating point arguments to the built-in `<=>` operator:

> [...] the operator yields a prvalue of type `std::partial_ordering`. The expression `a <=> b` yields
>
> - `std::partial_ordering::less` if `a` is less than `b`
> - `std::partial_ordering::greater` if a is greater than `b`
> - `std::partial_ordering::equivalent` if `a` is equivalent to `b` (`-0 <=> +0` is equivalent)
> - **`std::partial_ordering::unordered` (NaN `<=>` anything is unordered)**

So, in brief, applying `<=>` to a floating point value of NaN results in `std::partial_ordering::unordered`.

When evaluating an expression like `a <=> b == 0` or `a <=> b < 0`, if either `a` or `b` is NaN then the whole expression returns `false`, which makes sense coming from NaN's built-in behaviour ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/partial_ordering)). Of course, `std::partial_ordering::unordered == std::partial_ordering::unordered` holds true or else this type wouldn't be very useful.

If you can otherwise guarantee the absence of pathological floating point values, take a look at [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445206/is-there-a-wrapper-for-floating-point-numbers-in-c20-that-would-enable-me-to-d) for a floating point wrapper whose comparisons yield `std::strong_ordering`.