# Does std::set work correctly with a type that compares as std::partial_ordering?

Tags: c++, set, c++20, spaceship-operator, partial-ordering

I came across this when defaulting the three-way-comparison operator (spaceship operator).

Let's consider this small example:

```
#include <set>
#include <limits>

struct A {
    float x;
    auto operator<=>(A const& other) const = default; // will be std::partial_ordering
};

int main()
{
    std::set<A>{ A{.x = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()}, A{.x = 1.f} };
}
```

Here we have a struct `A` that has one member of type `float` and defaults the <=> operator. Due tot he `float` member, the return type of the <=> operator will be `std::partial_ordering`. Partial ordering allows the category `std::partial_ordering::unordered` for elements that cannot be put into a specific order relative to other elements. For float this would affect `nan` for example. Any comparison of a float to nan will yield false.

Now, containers like `std::set` order their elements for being able to do binary search. For this they basically do a `<` comparison. Wouldn't this be broken for any type defining a partial ordering? In the example above, I can create a set of `A` and it compiles just fine. This seems like a pitfall to me because I assume that as soon as an element is inserted into the set that yields `std::partial_ordering::unordered`, the ordering inside the set would basically be broken, and various operations on the set would just cease to work correctly. Is my assumption correct?

Now, I know that it is possible in C++ to actually compare floats using a strong ordering. For this the function `std::strong_order` exists. So to fix the code, I could manually implement the three-way-comparison operator like this:

```
struct A {
    float x;
    auto operator<=>(A const& other) const{
        return std::strong_order(x, other.x);
    }
};
```

For this exmaple this is easy. But for larger structs/classes we are basically back to having to manually write comparisons that check member by member. Is there any way to achieve this comparison behaviour while still being able to default the spaceship operator? (without writing a wrapper class for float that offers strong order comparison)

tl;dr: To my understanding, set::set requires a strict weak ordering to work correctly. Still, I can construct a set using an element type that only offers a partial_ordering. This seems prone to causing bugs.

The example code is here, in case you're interested: https://godbolt.org/z/q4a95czTr

Comment: `set` requires a strict weak ordering.  `std::partial_ordering` does not provide that so you are in undefined behavior land.

Comment: using a float as a key for a set is potentially risky anyway due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: for the last paragraph, afaict `set::set` only requires a strict weak ordering *on it's element* to work correctly, you may never insert `NAN` to it and it'd work. Besides, there is generally nothing `std::set` can do to determine the `Compare` actually fulfill the requirement.

Comment: @appleapple: I understand that it is only a problem if there are actually nans in the container. It would be possible in theory though to create a version of `set` that requires the element type to define a `weak_ordering`, wouldn't it (i.e. require it to have an `operator<=>` returning at least `std::weak_ordering` via concepts)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles: I don't see how floating point inaccuracies that occur when doing arithmetic play a role when using floats as keys for a set. Floats that are not NaN etc. will have a strong order, that should be enough.

Comment: @bweber I'd rather the standard doesn't impose more unnecessary constraint. also it still cannot be sure if the result is correct (even if the type is)

Comment: @bweber fwiw, you can simply use alias template and constraint to create what you want.

Comment: @bweber for example, `std::set<float>` already has such potential problem (even though the type is correct).

Comment: it wont cause the set to have undefined behaviour but it may give you duplicate entries if you have calculations that produce slightly different results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wouldn't this be broken for any type defining a partial ordering?

No, not necessarily. I'm going to use `float` as the canonical example of a type with partial ordering, but the argument here applies to any partially ordered type.

`std::set<float>`, for instance, is not an inherently broken type. `std::set<float>{1.f, 2.f, 3.f}` will do exactly what you want, for instance. Indeed, it will do what you want for any `float`s you put into it... as long as they are not `NaN`.

There are really two approaches to this problem:

- you could put it in the type system, requiring that `<=>` yields at least `weak_ordering`, thus rejecting `std::set<float>`
- you could put it in the value system, and say it's undefined behavior if you have a partial ordering that compares as unordered. With `<=>`, if `a <=> b` is valid and yields a `partial_ordering`, you can `assert` that it's not `unordered`. That is, an operation is defined on a domain of values - not necessarily on every possible value in the type - and an algorithm is valid as long as the provided values are elements of the domain on which the operation is defined.

Rust does it the former way (which requires manually providing a comparison operation if you want to do something like sort a `Vec<f32>` - where that comparison probably just panics in the unordered case), and C++ has always done it the latter way - `std::set<float>` and sorting a `std::vector<float>` have always been valid in general, just with the precondition that `NaN` is not present in those containers (i.e. `NaN` is outside of the domain of the comparison).

I'm not sure that one approach is necessary better than the other. Rust's approach requires you to explicitly handle the unordered case, which is more tedious if you just don't have `NaN`s. In some sense, the C++ approach is more bug prone - since the unordered case won't be typically handled by simply aborting the program (although nothing stops you from writing an equivalently-buggy comparison in the Rust model).

Comment: I do of course understand that it only becomes a problem when nan enters the container. One valid point, that I didn't think of, is that the problem also existed with `std::set<float>` beforehand. It just feels to me like a bug waiting to happen because it's more hidden. Someone writes a struct with a spaceship operator, and uses the struct in a set/map. Later on, someone adds a float field to the struct, the defaulted spaceship operator will automatically update, and viola, the existing usage in combination with `set` becomes unsafe.

Comment: Do I assume correct that there is no way to make the defaulted spaceship operator use strong float comparison?

Comment: @bweber That's correct, defaulted spaceship just does member-wise comparison. If you want to use `std::strong_order` (or `std::weak_order`) then you either need to manually write your `<=>` or use a type like `StrongOrdered<float>` instead of `float` for you rmember.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess there is no way around the wrapper type then.

Comment: @bweber reading this answer and comments it reminded me I had similar "problem" as you and Barry answered it with few helper implementations, here it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/59445868/700825